# precompile reflection?

Tags: .net, reflection

I notice in my unit test the first test with a class using reflection is slow. Is there a way i can tell the compiler these classes will all be used for reflection so precompile it now so it wont lag during runtime? (I run these unit test often.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about being able to "precompile" individual classes. Maybe if they are all grouped under a single assembly.

What you could do is to split your tests into categories. One category could be running speed. Run faster tests more often and slower tests less often (leave them running over night or run them just once a day etc.)

Answer (score 0):

To precompile reflection sounds like an oxymoron. How about mocking the slow parts?

Comment: i hear its cache after you run it the first time. so i am asking like cache it right away i guess. mocking the slow parts would take too long to write and i probably have to write it for each class